# How to retrieve the Video thumbnail in android

Tags: android, gridview, sd-card

I want to retrieve the video thumbnail from the SDCARD and show in `GridView` for both Android OS version 1.5  and 2.0. By using `MediaStore` class I can retrieve the thumbnail in only 2.0 and above but I want one common code to retrieve the Video thumbnail for 1.5 and 2.0 also.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. The simplest API exists beginning in android-8, and is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317665/how-to-get-thumbnail-for-video-in-my-sdcard-android-data-mypackage-files-folder/5278269#5278269).