# How to get thumbnail for video in my /sdcard/Android/data/mypackage/files folder?

Tags: android, video, thumbnails

Query to `MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` returns only video in `/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA`

But I want to get thumbnails for video in my `/sdcard/Android/data/mypackage/files` folder. Is it possible ?

Here is part of my code:

```
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    String[] proj = {
                    BaseColumns._ID
    };

    Cursor c = cr.query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do
        {
            int id = c.getInt(0);
            Bitmap b = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
            Log.d("*****My Thumbnail*****", "onCreate bitmap " + b);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            iv.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
        while( c.moveToNext() );
    }         
    c.close();
```

Answer (score 126):

If you are on android-8 (Froyo) or above, you can use [ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Comment: is it possible to supply video uri instead of exact path?? video player plays the video uri but thumbnail creation asks for a String in the constructor

Comment: @Matthew , how to get the frames of an video file in android

Comment: well , i tried using Thumbnail.createVideoThumbnail but i got the result to be a bit of gibberish . Please this the [photo](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/89231635/device-2012-07-05-162525.png)

Comment: Sorry , it was my problem , the video itself wasn't getting recorded properly :P

Comment: Hi guys, I can't figured out why its returning a null using a Samsung device 2.3.6.

Comment: @Matthew What about server side path?

Comment: What is the exact path of the thumb after or how would you go about retrieving it?

Comment: Working great, but is there a way to take the first frame of the video not the thumbnail???, because the Thumbnail is random depending on the length of the video, and also the quality of the thumbnail image is very low.

Answer (score 29):

Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) it will fetch the thumbnail in async.

```
 Glide.with(context)
                    .load(videoFilePath) // or URI/path
                    .into(imgView); //imageview to set thumbnail to
```

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa Its working fine for me bro. check your path or share your code snippet

Comment: Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: If you are dealing with a local video file, make sure to send Glide the file String or Uri: `file:///absolute/path/to/video/file.mp4`. The `file:///` is needed here to find the video file by Glide.

Comment: @Ajji God bless you :)

Answer (score 12):

**3 ways to get a thumbnail from a video:**

1. The best way is to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). It will do all the work in the background, load the thumbnail right into the ImageView and even can show animation when loading. It can work with Uri, byte[] and many other sources.
   As @Ajji mentioned:

   ```
   Glide.with(context)
               .load(videoFilePath) // or URI/path
               .into(imgView); //imageview to set thumbnail to
   ```
2. If you just need a bitmap in the most efficient way - use `ThumbnailUtils`. 
   In my case, it produced a bitmap with a size of 294 912 bytes (video taken with a camera of Nexus5X - 1280x720) and the quality was the same as in the next approach. After you compress into JPEG with 90 it will generate a jpeg file of ~30Kb.

   ```
   Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
   MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
   ```
3. The last approach is to use `MediaMetadataRetriever`. But in my case, it produced a bitmap with size more than 6 times bigger than you got with `ThumbnailUtils` (with the same quality). So consider it as a last resort.

   ```
   MediaMetadataRetriever mMMR = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                       mMMR.setDataSource(mContext, mAttachment.getUri());
                       bmp = mMMR.getFrameAtTime();
   ```

---

P.S.: Don't forget that images in `Bitmap`, `byte[]` and `real file .jpeg` formats can be easily converted in any direction within these types. In case of Uri's you often don't have real path to the source file but you can always get the byte stream from it like this:

```
    InputStream in =  mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

and with this input stream you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) and forget the reflection:

```
/**
 *
 * @param path
 *            the path to the Video
 * @return a thumbnail of the video or null if retrieving the thumbnail failed.
 */
public static Bitmap getVideoThumbnail(String path) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever fmmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();  

    try {
        fmmr.setDataSource(path);            

        final byte[] data = fmmr.getEmbeddedPicture();

        if (data != null) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        }

        if (bitmap == null) {
            bitmap = fmmr.getFrameAtTime();   
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        bitmap = null;
    } finally {
        fmmr.release();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Can we use it in UIL (https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for Creating thumbnail of Videos and skip Image? UIL needs one configuration setup per app so i need a decoder that can skip Images and just decode Videos

Answer (score 3):

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inDither = false;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

Bitmap bitmapThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(mActivity.getContentResolver(),
     Long.parseLong(video_id), 
     Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, 
     options);
```

Use Options to load bitmap of decrease the bitmap size..

Comment: This works fairly enough. Tested on Android 6.0+ with the Tecno N5

Comment: @PankajTalaviya so you want him to also set your video id to the code? what the heck? it's your video, use your own id for the video!!

Comment: This is deprecated with API-29.

Answer (score 3):

see @Ajji 's answer :

```
 Glide.with(context)
                    .load(videoFilePath) // or URI/path
                    .into(imgView); //imageview to set thumbnail to
```

It sometimes returns black image, this issue is already mentioned in Glide library's issues

Use this code:

```
 BitmapPool bitmapPool = Glide.get(activity).getBitmapPool();
                int microSecond = 6000000;// 6th second as an example
                VideoBitmapDecoder videoBitmapDecoder = new VideoBitmapDecoder(microSecond);
                FileDescriptorBitmapDecoder fileDescriptorBitmapDecoder = new FileDescriptorBitmapDecoder(videoBitmapDecoder, bitmapPool, DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888);
                Glide.with(activity)
                        .load(videoPath)
                        .asBitmap()
                        .override(50,50)// Example
                        .videoDecoder(fileDescriptorBitmapDecoder)
                        .into(holder.ivFirstUpload);
```

Answer (score 2):

Get video thumbnail from **VIDEO_ID**:

```
public static Drawable getVideoThumbnail(Context context, int videoID) {
        try {
            String[] projection = {
                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA,
            };
            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor = cr.query(
                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, 
                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID + "=?", 
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(videoID) }, 
                    null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return Drawable.createFromPath(cursor.getString(0));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method with any `Uri`:

```
public static Bitmap getVideoFrame(Uri uri, Context context) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(context, uri);
    return retriever.getFrameAtTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar answer to Matthew Willis but with added reflection. Why? because science.

```
/**
 *
 * @param path
 *            the path to the Video
 * @return a thumbnail of the video or null if retrieving the thumbnail failed.
 */
public static Bitmap getVidioThumbnail(String path) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
    // MediaMetadataRetriever is available on API Level 8 but is hidden until API Level 10
    Class<?> clazz = null;
    Object instance = null;
    try {
        clazz = Class.forName("android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever");
        instance = clazz.newInstance();
        final Method method = clazz.getMethod("setDataSource", String.class);
        method.invoke(instance, path);
        // The method name changes between API Level 9 and 10.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            bitmap = (Bitmap) clazz.getMethod("captureFrame").invoke(instance);
        } else {
            final byte[] data = (byte[]) clazz.getMethod("getEmbeddedPicture").invoke(instance);
            if (data != null) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            }
            if (bitmap == null) {
                bitmap = (Bitmap) clazz.getMethod("getFrameAtTime").invoke(instance);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        bitmap = null;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (instance != null) {
                clazz.getMethod("release").invoke(instance);
            }
        } catch (final Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: this code do something that Matthew code dosen't , it getting the thumbnail of MKV video :) ( not only science )

Answer (score 0):

If you are directly creating thumbnails as follows

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

> Then there is a problem with this method if your are creating thumbnails for large video set(for large number of videos). the application will freeze until all the thumbnails are loaded because all the process are executing in the main thread.

**Use SuziLoader**

This loader will load the thumbnails for the videos which is locally stored on your filesystem in background.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/video.mp4";
ImageView mThumbnail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

SuziLoader loader = new SuziLoader(); //Create it for once
loader.with(MainActivity.this) //Context
    .load(path) //Video path
    .into(mThumbnail) // imageview to load the thumbnail
    .type("mini") // mini or micro
    .show(); // to show the thumbnail
```

> To get this dependency use the following steps

**Step 1.** Add the JitPack repository to your build file
Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

**Step 2.** Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.sushinpv:SuziVideoThumbnailLoader:0.1.0'
}
```

ADD READ EXTERNAL STORAGE Permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to this code snippet:

```
img.setImageBitmap(ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(
                   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/"+getItem(position),
                   MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA };
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int vidsCount = 0;
        if (c != null) {
            vidsCount = c.getCount();
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                String path = c.getString(0);
                Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
            }
            c.close();
        }
```

Comment: You might to explain more detailed why this will help OP to fix their issue.