# Video Thumbnail android 1.6

Tags: android, video, thumbnails, sd-card

I want to display thumbnail of a video from SD card in an imageView.

I know theres new Video.Thumbnail class available but its from android 2.1 and I want this to work on 1.6.

From research I got to know that theres some MediaMetadataRetriever interface but its giving me runtime exceptions.

Can neone please help.

Answer (score 0):

MediaMetadataRetriever is a private API and not expected to work across Android versions. Your best bet is to use the method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317665/how-to-get-thumbnail-for-video-in-my-sdcard-android-data-mypackage-files-folder/5278269#5278269) if it is at all possible to target Android-8 (Froyo).