# display video thumbnails from sdcard in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get thumbnail for video in my /sdcard/Android/data/mypackage/files folder ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317665/how-to-get-thumbnail-for-video-in-my-sdcard-android-data-mypackage-files-folder)

Hello All

In my android application i am recording a video and saving this in sdcard.
Now what i require is display this video as thumbnails in my application.

I tried all solutions from [Android: Is it possible to display video thumbnails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334694/android-is-it-possible-to-display-video-thumbnails)
The issue is i need the video from sdcard path and am not understanding as how to get it.

I tried below code

```
int id = **"The Video's ID"** 
ImageView iv = (ImageView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagePreview); 
ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver(); 
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
options.inSampleSize = 1; 
Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, id,MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options); 
iv.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
```

But could not understand as how to get the video from sdcard path.

Please share your valuable suggestions

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out `ThumbnailUtils` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317665/how-to-get-thumbnail-for-video-in-my-sdcard-android-data-mypackage-files-folder/5278269#5278269), provided you are on Android 8 (Froyo) or later.