# Taking first frame of video as thumbnail in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to store the thumbnail image for video after the user start recording, because i want to use the only few video to list which is stored under specific instead of all video from sdcard.

If i want to shoe all video i got the thumbnails form MediaStore class, but i need for specific video i have to store the thumbnails separately for the particular video. Any suggest 
some idea to achieve this.

If it is possible tell me how to capture the surface View of camera to save it as bitmap image for use it as Thumbnails.

Thanks

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't take the first frame, it will be most likely black or otherwise useless. Using something like the 30th frame or 1% of video length should give much better results.

Comment: could you give some sample to capture the 30th frame

Comment: @user555806: Sorry, I can't, that's why I made a comment and not an answer.

Comment: By the way, you should have a look at some of your questions and accept answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first frame can be taken using the NDK and ffmpeg, but it's more trouble than it's worth.

The simple way is to use `ThumbnailUtils` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317665/how-to-get-thumbnail-for-video-in-my-sdcard-android-data-mypackage-files-folder/5278269#5278269), provided you are on android-8 (Froyo) or later.

Comment: This is long overdue, but this is not a correct answer.  ThumbnailUtils does not get the first frame, it's a frame from the middle of the video.

Comment: @Karthi - MediaMetadataRetriever is what you are looking for.