# android get online video file and extract thumbnail

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a video that is stored on Amazons S3 (I have a public link to a .mp4 file) and extract a thumbnail from the first frame of the video.

There are questions here about doing this but targeting local files or Youtube files.

Does anyone have a example of doing this but targeting an online file?

I'm trying the MediaMetadataRetriever class but I can't put it to work.

Thanks

Comment: [this link][1] might give you some guideline how to achieve your goal.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317665/how-to-get-thumbnail-for-video-in-my-sdcard-android-data-mypackage-files-folder/5278269#5278269

Comment: I already found allot of similar answers, but I was trying to get the thumbnail without downloading the entire file.