# Is there any way to generate video thumbnail without ffmpeg?

Tags: laravel, thumbnails

I was trying to generate video thumbnail in Laravel using ffmpeg, but the shared hosting (like Godady) doesn't support ffmpeg due to its consuming a lot of resources!
So, is there anyway to do this (like reading the file byte after byte).
Thanks.

Comment: There are 3rd party services you could use such as [AWS Elastic Transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/) which among other things can create thumbnails for a video.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  I'm looking for a solution that I can code it (if that was possible).

Comment: and why would you thought you can't code using aws elastic transcoder?

Comment: I meant that I need a solution without any 3rd party, there is no enough budget for that (at this moment) :/

Comment: Generating video thumbnail in php without ffmpeg is very difficult. but you can use javascript to generate a thumbnail and store it with php. If you think this is a good idea, I put a snippets code in answer.

Comment: My project is RESTFul API (Laravel) and I need the thumbnail for the Android application, is there any way to get the thumbnail from the Android (Java)? 
And please, put the Javascript snippets maybe I'll need it later :D!
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the video can be played back in the browser you could try using the Canvas feature of html5 to playback the video in a canvas and then post a still from that video to your server using javascript... Maybe you could even automate it, or if you only have a few dozen videos do it by hand...

Comment: My project is RESTFul API (Laravel) and I need the thumbnail for the Android application, is there any way to get the thumbnail from the Android (Java)?

Comment: Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317665/how-to-get-thumbnail-for-video-in-my-sdcard-android-data-mypackage-files-folder, but that is for another question